# Best practice for a typeorm migration in a serverless app

Tags: orm, database-migration, typeorm, serverless

We use typeorm into a serverless application. And now we are thinking about migration running on production.

In classical application `migration run` command is a part of ci/cd pipeline. But if we copy this pattern to a serverless application, then we get 100 ci/cd pipelines (one for each lambda function). And when we update 100 lambdas at once, then 100 migration scripts run concurrently.

It looks not good IMHO. I hope there is another best practice for serverless apps.

Answer (score 1):

I have a reasonbly large serverless application with a lot of functions, and I treat the DB as seperate from the functions, I have a central db folder  with all TypeORM entities and migrations in it. I have a pipeline which triggers on changes within the migrations folder, this runs before deployment of any functions and simply runs any new migrations.

This setup hasn't worked out too badly for me, just need to be cognisant when writing migrations that I am careful about dropping columns / renaming fields etc, knowing there will be a brief lag between migration completion and function deployment, so the 'old' code could be running with migrated DB for a minute or 2 before the deployment of 'new' function code is finished.

PS: If you found a better solution I'd be really keen to hear it, I have no idea what 'best practises' there are for this sort of stuff in serverless world

Comment: thanks for replay. We are doing a pretty same thing. The only difference is that our migration executor is also lambda function. By the way do you use yarn workspaces for managing your lambda's code?

Comment: @alexey2baranov not using yarn workspaces, but we are using lerna to manage a monorepo

Comment: @wilson208 we did something similar, although currently without a ORM, but we keep the migrations inside custom resources. Basically a new custom resource for every new version of the schema. The benefit of this is that cloudformation will keep track of the dependencies between them (if you setup dependsOn) i.e. Upgrading and downgrading in the correct order. We are not in production with this yet though.